# Run fails while debug ok

Tags: debugging, lua

I have the following 3 functions:

```
function getName() -- returns filename without ext
    local files = scandir(currentDir())
    local name = nil

    for i = 1, #files do
        if isValidExt( getExt(files[i]) ) then 
            name = getFilename(files[i]) 
            break 
        end
    end

    return name
end
```

```
function currentDir()
    local string = debug.getinfo(1).source
    local endPoint = getLastOcurrence(string, '/')
    local dir = string.sub(string, 2, endPoint)
    return dir
end
```

```
function getLastOcurrence(str, char) 
    local last = string.find(string.reverse(str), char, 1, true)
    return #str - last
 end
```

The strange thing is that debugging ends without issues, while running gives the error:

```
...\Downloader.lua:22: attempt to perform arithmetic on local 'last' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
...\Downloader.lua:22: in function 'getLastOcurrence'
...\Downloader.lua:39: in function 'currentDir'
...\Downloader.lua:50: in function 'getName'
```

What could cause such a difference between debug and run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that when you are not in debug mode you compile your code and strip debug information, so `debug.getinfo(1).source` is not a filename (and does not contain a `/` character). Try to print its value in the `currentDir()` function.

Comment: I dont think that's the issue here, I think the interpreter auto-converts all '/' to '\' anyways since I'm building from Windows.

Comment: Maybe my tentative explanation of why there is no `/` in the filename is wrong but the problem is *certainly* that there is no `/` in the filename. Do what I said: add `print(string)` after the `local string = debug.getinfo(1).source` line. Another possibility is that you are running from the directory where the source file is...

Comment: Anyway, there *is* no `/` in the string you pass to `getLastOcurrence`, which crashes when `char` is not in `str` (because, as the error message says, `last` is `nil`).

Comment: Yeah you were right I added   `string = string.gsub(string, '\\', '/')` before calling `getLastOcurrence` and now it works, thanks. :)